# Calling rest api from angular2 results in undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

Iam struggling to figure out, whats wrong with my code. Iam trying to call a rest api from my angular code, but it results in "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined".

My code in the component looks like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void{
    this.getWod();
  }

  getWod(): void {
    let id;
    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
      id = +params['id'];
    })
    this.wodService.getWod(id).then(wod => this.wod = wod);
    console.log(this.wod);
  }
```

In the console and at the backend, I can see that the backend is being called correctly. The network tab in the console reads:

```
wod: {id: 16, name: "test name", description: "test description", wod_type_id: 3, wod_category_id: 3}
```

In the corrosponding html page for the component I simply have:

```
<div>{{wod.id}}</div>
```

The console.log method above results in a "Undefined", I simply dosen't know why?

UPDATED:

My getWod sevice code looks like this:

```
  getWod(id: number): Promise<Wod>{
    const url = `${this.getWodUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get(url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json().wod as Wod)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Ay ideas?

Comment: you forgot to show us the part where you declare `wod` in your component. The problem is probably there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the `div>` to

```
<div>{{wod?.id}}</div> <!--? will stop the reference to id if wod is undefined-->
```

Or just initialize your `this.wod` property in the component.

Having said that I believe the `console.log` you have shown in the question isn't generated from that line since the getWod function is asynchronous.

Change your component's getWod() function to

```
getWod(): void {
    let id;
    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
      id = +params['id'];
    })
    this.wodService.getWod(id).then(function(data){
        this.wod = data;
    }); 
  }
```

Assuming your service is written correctly, you should see a valid response.

Comment: you're right, I get an "undefined" error with <div *ngIf="wod && wod.id">{{wod.id}}</div> and with <div>{{wod?.id}}</div>. I ried changing the getWod() function to the above, but receives an compile error: "Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<Wod>'.)". I updatd the original question with the code from the getWod service.

Comment: @Tony I was assuming you were using observable, I have updated my answer based on your service code, please give it a try now!

Comment: Thank you Ali, this works perfectly. Maybe I should be using observables. I'am just getting started with Angular2 with the official tutorials (tour of heroes) and the angular2 book. I guess I will get to observables at some time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well at the point you're requesting your api (this takes a bit of time) your template is already rendered (or rendering..) If you declared your property `wod` without creating an object it is `undefined` at this time.

Two simple options to avoid this would be either in your template directly, for example:

`<div *ngIf="wod && wod.id">{{wod.id}}</div>` (or as seen in the other answer with the `elvis` operator: `<div>{{wod?.id}}</div>` which would result in an empty `div` instead of a non-existant)

or you preset it with an object of that type (proper way would be to use an `interface` for it or even create a new object of a certain model `class`, at this point i just show an simple example).

`wod: any = { id: '' }`